# Docker-compose: See what environmental variables are set within a container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cookiecutter-django

I have a `django-cookiecutter` project that has multiple containers:

- django
- postgres
- caddy
- etc

When I deploy, I'm getting an error that the Postgres db cannot authenticate the `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`.

I'm passing the `envs` in my `production.yml` file as:

```
services:
  django: &django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    image: authible_production_django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.django
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres
    command: /gunicorn.sh
```

**Question:**

Since the service is not able to authenticate, how can I check the `envs` within one of these containers?

I want to make sure the `envs` are being recognized.

Thank you for your help-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply execute `env` inside the container using `docker-compose`:

```
docker-compose exec django env
```